# Copy specific data from multiple workbooks into one master sheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have to copy data from 10+ workbooks and paste it into a master workbook.
All the workbooks are located in a folder on my desktop: C:\Users\xbv.......

All the workbooks contain a sheet named 'appendix B', I have to open each workbook, go to sheet 'appendix B’, select columns range C to F starting from row 6 to row ‘x'(the last row can vary in each workbook), cntrl+v (copy), and paste the data range into master worksheet. In the master worksheet, I paste the data in Columns A to D and continue pasting/appending the data as I copy data from more workbooks. Eventually, the master workbook has the data in columns A to D from every workbook in one sheet.

The columns range C to F and starting from row 6 always remains constant in all the sheets (appendix B ) of every workbook. Each workbook contains 7 sheets, but I am only interested in sheet ‘appendix B’

I have to repeat the same steps for 10-30 workbooks and continue pasting/appending the data into master sheet. So, I was wondering if someone could please help me to create a VBA code for this? I'm really new to VBA and would really appreciate your help!

```
Sub CopyRange()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim wkbDest As Workbook
    Dim wkbSource As Workbook
    Set wkbDest = ThisWorkbook
    Const strPath As String = "C:\Users\xbv\Desktop\group1\"
    ChDir strPath
    strExtension = Dir("*.xls*")
    Do While strExtension <> ""
        Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open(strPath & strExtension)
        With wkbSource
            .Sheets("Appendix B").Range("C6:F" & Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Copy wkbDest.Sheets("Master1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            .Sheets("Appendix C").Range("D6:Y" & Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row ).Copy wkbDest.Sheets("Master1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            .Sheets("Appendix D").Range("D5:I" & Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Copy wkbDest.Sheets("Master1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            .Close savechanges:=False
        End With
        strExtension = Dir
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm confused, did @Warcupine paste his answer in the edit of the post? Maybe delete the lines of `.Sheets("Appendix C")` and `.Sheets("Appendix D")` if they don't interest you. For the rest, the code seems clean and functional to me, do you run in an error?

Comment: @Notus_Panda no, I added a codeblock to the code that was present in the question...

Comment: maybe in this line `.Sheets("Appendix B").Range("C6:F" & Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Copy` ... if soon after you open the workbook, the active sheet is not "Appendix B", the `Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)` will be the row in the active sheet, not in sheet "Appendix B". So maybe try `.Sheets("Appendix B").Range("C6:F" & .Sheets("Appendix B").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Copy wkbDest.Sheets("Master1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)`

Comment: or use "with" :: `With (.Sheets("Appendix B"))` ...next line `.Range("C6:F" & .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Copy wkbDest.Sheets("Master1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)` ... next line `end with`